# Trouble Reading from URL (Android)

Tags: android, web-services, http

I have a homework assignment which I have to load lines of code from a file and output them into the log cat. Here's my code:

```
private void readFromURL (String requestedURL){

    try {
        URL myurl = new URL (requestedURL);
        InputStream mystream = myurl.openStream(); 
        Scanner myscan = new Scanner (mystream); 

        while (myscan.hasNextLine()) {
            String aLine = myscan.nextLine(); 
            Log.d ("works", aLine);
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException oops) {
                Log.d ("ERROR" , "Are you sure the URL is correct?" + oops);
    }
    catch (IOException oops_again)
    {
                Log.d ("ERROR", "Can't access the remote resource: " + oops_again);
    }
}
```

The readFromURL method is called from a button click. Whenever I run the application I get the IOException and it says "Can't access the remote resource: ". In the log cat.

The URL I'm trying to grab the info from is: http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~dulimarh/CS163H/courses.cgi

I have added internet to the permissions in the manifest.

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get an `InputStream` of the data to do what you need:

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String url) {
  HttpURLConnection con = null;
  URL url;
  InputStream is=null;
  try {
    url = new URL(url);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    // Start the query
    con.connect();
    is = con.getInputStream();
  }catch (IOException e) {
    //handle the exception !
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return is; 
}
```

Using this, you should be able to *echo* each line from the `InputStream` using `Log.d` - you should be able to figure out that part ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however i need to use the readFromURL method to fulfill the lab requirement.

Comment: @AdamJakiela Yes, I realize that. The reason I _specifically_ didn't correct your method is because you need to _learn_ what went wrong (yourself). We're not here to do your homework for you on Stack Overflow :) If you follow the logic in what I posted, you'll see that the answer is quite trivial.